# Citrix: "The My Knowledge Base will not be available for farm <my farm name>"

Tags: citrix

I get this error message everytime I do a discovery in Citrix:

> The My Knowledge Base will not be available for farm <my farm name>

Citrix server is run under VMWare and all privileges are assigned properly.

We followed this Citrix knowledge base article - [Error: The My Knowledge Features will not be available for farm](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX120113) - to no success.

Any suggestions? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom MMC console with the “Citrix Access Management Console” snap-in but with the “Add all extensions” box unchecked (in the Extensions tab) and all extensions unchecked except for “Presentation Server Extension”.  This has everything anybody really needs to manage a farm (applications, sessions, processes, etc), loads a little faster, and keeps the event log clear.  As an added benefit of using this custom console, since it no longer invokes the “My Knowledge Extension”, you can now use “LOCALHOST” as the only entry in the discovery server list **without having to put up with the “The My Knowledge feature will be unavailable”** message every time you open the console.  [This issue by the way has been cleverly resolved by Citrix in XA 5 for Windows Server 2008 … by getting rid of the “My Knowledge” feature entirely! J]

Additionally, if you copy this newly created mmc file that you just created to “C:\Program Files\Common Files\Citrix\Access Management Console – Framework” and make sure to name it cmi20.mmc (I would recommend renaming the original) and wipe out any %AppData%\CitrixMMC folder that exists (or at least the mmc (ok they are actually .msc) files), then this new, customized version of the MMC will be used for all of the default AMC icons, on the ICA Toolbar and in the Start Menu!